# No certificate for team (iOS compile error)

Tags: ios

what should I do to solve the following problem?

2018-10-05 10:38:46
note: Using new build system

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /uzmap/temp/E94hWYr9uYbBAPj/ios/UZApp.xcarchive

Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = Apple Push Services: com.HomegaB.app

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: No certificate for team '894QT93R4U' matching 'Apple Push Services: com.HomegaB.app' found: Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning. (in target 'UZApp')

Build system information
warning: The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.0. (in target 'UZApp')

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

** EXPORT FAILED **

error: archive not found at path '/uzmap/temp/E94hWYr9uYbBAPj/ios/UZApp.xcarchive'

Comment: As the error says, you need to ensure there is an associated push certificate against the app bundle ID. This is setup in the Apple Dev Center.

Comment: I used the Apple Push Service certificate to compile , so I failed... we should use iOS distribution certificate...